# Почему прокрутка до якоря не работает в браузере Firefox?

Tags: javascript

Имеется вот такой простой код, который работает везде, но в Firefox нет никакой реакции, выводит лишь console.log и все. Не могу понять, в чем дело...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href="#contact"]').click(function(){
    var el = $('.footer');
    console.log('Click');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top}, 1000);
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href="#contact"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var el = $('.footer');
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#contact{
  width: 590px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6B86A6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
<div id="contact" class="footer"></div>
```

добавьте в селектор для анимации **html**

Comment: Теперь, понял в чем была проблема... спасибо большое, буду дальше стараться писать кроссбраузерный код!